# How to wait for elements to be loaded in DOM in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, selector, wait

I have a problem with getting selector of an element in DOM, I placed the script source at the bottom of the HTML page and I also tried to wrap all codes in a function with *"DOMContentLoaded"* event, and it is still not working. in addition it disables jQuery that I am using it in my project.

This is how I get the selector:

```
const char = document.querySelectorAll('.text');
const num = document.querySelectorAll('span');
```

When I try to catch the selector in a function it works because it waits for the DOM to be loaded.
I want to use these two variables in my code many times so I want them to be globally available and avoid repeating same line in many places.

Is there any way to wait for the DOM to be loaded and then get the elements selector globally?

Comment: Native JS doesn't "disable" jQuery. But also: if you're using jQuery why are you using native JS? It makes sense to stick with one or the other.

Comment: In order to wait for the dom to be loaded, you can use `window.onload=yourfunction`

Comment: @Andy I use jQuery for drag and drop functionality and native JS for saving the position of elements and manipulating localStorage and also changing style.

Comment: Define them a global. Onload or DOMContentLoaded set the variables.

Comment: @epascarello can you please explain it a little bit more how should I do it? you mean I should define a DOMContentLoaded function and out of it the variable? sorry I have very limited experience in JS.

Comment: 1/2 ... The wanted behavior which the OP describes is covered by [live `HTMLCollection`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) only, that, at any time, reflect the mutations within the document. Thus the OP's queries need to be based on [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) and/or [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

Comment: 2/2 ... On the other hand [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) is more flexible with its query language and less expensive too since it returns a [static `NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define them globally and set the with DOMContentLoaded

```js
let char;
let num;
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    char = document.querySelectorAll('.text');
    num = document.querySelectorAll('span');
});

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log(char);
  console.log(num);
});
```

```html
<div class="text"><span></span></div>
<div class="text"><span></span></div>

<button>Test</button>
```

Or make a getter

```js
const elems = {
  domChars: null,
  domNum: null,
  get chars() {
    if (this.domChars === null) {
      this.domChars = document.querySelectorAll('.text');
    }
    return this.domChars;
  },
  get nums() {
    if (this.domNum === null) {
      this.domNum = document.querySelectorAll('span');
    }
    return this.domNum;
  }
};


document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log(elems.chars);
  console.log(elems.nums);
});
```

```html
<div class="text"><span></span></div>
<div class="text"><span></span></div>

<button>Test</button>
```

Comment: The second solution is working it is the best solution for this problem thank you. But there is an issue because querySelectorAll is generating an array it expect also to have an empty array I declared both variables like this:  **`domChars: null || [] `** and it is working very fine Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: `domChars: null || [] ` um, that makes no sense. It would just be `domChars: []` Not sure what bringing back an empty array has to do with how that property is set initially.